# MACE correlation filter - any suggested values of of u?

Tags: fourier-transform, filter-design, correlation

I am trying to understand the MACE correlation filter as per the paper

> Mahalanobis, A., Kumar, B.V.K.V., Casasent, D.: Minimum average correlation
>   energy ﬁlters. Appl. Opt. 26, 3630–3633 (1987)

The equation to train the MACE filter is this

[image]

I however am abit confused about what values you use for u.  From my reading u, is an N x 1 vector containing the desired peak values for the training images.  Is this something I would just set to 1, could someone offer some suggested values

I have found a basic implementation in matlab from [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2604/correlation-filter-output-range-normalization) (code posted below) but it does not give any definition to how I would go about deciding what u is?

```
D = diag(mean(abs(X),2));
% inv(A) * B = A \ B
XDX = ctranspose(X) * (D \ X);
h = (D \ X) * (XDX \ u);
H = reshape(h, size(I));
```

I will appreciate any help with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nth entry in the u vector corresponds to the value of the desired correlation peak of the nth training image. Typically you set u to be all ones if you have only images from the positive class. Entries corresponding to negative class example images are typically set to zero.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the `D` matrix should be the average of the magnitude **squares** of the columns. I.e the average power spectrum:

`D = diag(mean(abs(X),2));`

Should be

`D = diag(mean(abs(X).^2,2));`